# How to check if two points (characters) in an image are at the same horizontal level?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm a beginner and would like to know methods that could be used to check if two characters in an image are at the same horizontal level. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking for a simple method using python image processing.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [help/on-topic]. you are expected to do research before asking, and to have _tried_ to solve the problem on your own (show your effort).

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenCV or PIL library. These libraries can help finding the bounding box/rectangle of the characters. Then you can use that info to compare positions and verify if they are on same level.

check: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html